# Ubuntu stuck suspending console while going to sleep

Tags: suspend

Every now and then, about 1 in 10 times when I suspend my Ubuntu, I get a black screen and console with the following text:

```
PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
PM: Preparing system for mem sleep
Freezing user space processes ... done.
Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... done.
PM: Entering mem sleep
Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
```

And it stays like this indefinitely; I have to force restart it. I once left it like this for an hour. This might be a bug, but it might just as well be something I touched. I do that and break things a lot.

Edit to add: I'm using Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: ``use no_console_suspend to debug`` try this, maybe?

Comment: I don't use a console to suspend. It didn't help. Actually it caused the problem.

Comment: What I'm suggesting is that you do use the console to suspend and with the given option.

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelDebuggingTricks - check this out to understand the ``no_console_suspend``